# What is the use of event bus and how to use it

Tags: java, android

I got the problem when one activity is in active state when i click the notification for the activity it cannot refreshed. So the suggestion is event bus. Can any one explain the event bus concept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why people use message/event buses in their code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987391/why-people-use-message-event-buses-in-their-code)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, event bus is not your only solution. You can set your activity's `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and in your activity's `onNewIntent()` method re init your activity. When you get a notification if your activity is in active state, your activity'll catch notification click event in it's `onNewIntent` method.

If you want to use Event Bus for this operations you can use Otto Bus. You can find it's example implementation from the link below.

http://square.github.io/otto/

Good luck.