# Blocking set in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, java-threads

I need to use multiple threads, some of them are running, some of them are waiting until some other threads would wake them up. Lets say I have thread A, B, C, D and want to be able to wake/sleep any thread from any other. So, for instance, I want A to have a possibility to wake/sleep B, C, D; I want B to have a possibility to wake/sleep A, C, D etc For this purpose I decided to go for BlockingQueue so that I add kind of messages to BlockingQueue i.e.

```
blockingQueue.put("Start A"); or blockingQueue.put("Stop A");
```

And this queue is shared among all the threads so that every thread waits until message for it appears. However, this approach, apparently, has a big disadvantage: when some thread is listening for message which is intended for this thread (thread A waits for message "Start A" and must ignore all other messages like "Start B" etc), it must explicitly check if message for him is in the queue so I must use .contains() method and write some code in order to implement what I need. However, perhaps, there is some kind of blocking set for this purpose. The set which would allows to do the following:

```
blockingSet.get(E) //wait until element E appears in the set
```

Comment: There is something strange in your question and the use of BlockingQueue. Could you please give us the bigger picture? Why do you want A to sleep B?

Comment: You may want a `Map<String,CyclicBarrier>` or something similar, where each thread waits on its own `CyclicBarrier`, and each thread that wants to talk to it, looks up the correct barrier in the map. But this is easy for wake - what did you have in mind for sleep? The threads themselves will have to check if anybody told them to sleep, you can't force a thread to suspend itself.

Comment: @TobiasOtto I'm trying to create something like small framework for internal usage. So the main idea is that we will have many threads and want to have a single channel of communication between them so that any thready may contact any other

Comment: Something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern. Please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987391/why-people-use-message-event-buses-in-their-code

Comment: @TobiasOtto yes, exactly, but between threads, not between JMS brokers

Comment: Still not clear what exactly do you want to do. Do you want to pass various messages/commands, or is it really just starting and stopping a particular thread?